# Get pose bones which were animated in a strip

Tags: python, animation, nla-editor

I created an animation with some of my pose bones and created a strip in the nla editor.
How can I access the strip and find out which pose bones were needed for this animation via python?

I took a look in the animation data of the armature object

```
C.active_object.animation_data.nla_tracks[0].strips[0]
```

but I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container for fcurves are actions. So you need to find the corresponding action for the strip.

I.e.

```
track = C.active_object.animation_data.tracks[0]
#get the action from the first strip
action = track.strips[0].action

for fcu in action.fcurves:
    print(fcu.data_path, fcu.array_index)
```